# Como hacer para volver a una ventana abierta desde otra ventana?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

resulta que tengo una ventana menu, en ella tengo un boton que me abre otra ventana. Lo que quiero es que cuando aprete ese boton para ir a mi otra ventana, mi ventana menu no se cierre. y que al volver desde mi nueva ventana a la ventana menu esta no se duplique.

Lo que me ha pasado es que cuando vuelvo de mi ventana a mi ventana menu, me duplica la ventana menu ya existente.

Este es el boton de mi ventana menu que me lleva a mi nueva ventana:

```
 private void btn_AgregarClientes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Agregar agmain = new Agregar();
            agmain.Show();

        }
```

Y este es el boton que me hace volver a mi ventana menu

```
  private void Btn_ir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow miwin = new MainWindow();          
            miwin.Show();
            this.Close();




    }
```

Y me lo duplica, cada vez que vuelvo. El problema es que se podria solucionar añadiendo un .close() a mi ventana menu cada vez que yo ingrese a mi nueva ventana. Pero no quiero hacer eso, necesito que mi primera ventana menu no se cierre, y que cuando desde mi otra ventana vuelva, se cierre mi nueva ventana y me traiga la ventana menu original

Se que es un poco enredado espero se entienda. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo que entendí, tienes varias opciones:

Supongo que MainWindow es tu ventana inicial, por lo tanto no debería cerrarse ni duplicarse si solo estás abriendo una ventana adicional encima, las ventanas no hacen eso por defecto, bastaría con cambiar el método de cierre de la ventana Agregar a esto:

```
private void Btn_ir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Y listo, tu ventana MainWindow debiera estar activa, solo tendrías que traerla al frente si es que se ocultó, imagino que sabes hacerlo, reitero, mientras TU no la cierres no necesitas volver a crearla.

Otra forma es que en vez de Show() uses ShowDialog() con esto tu ventana Agregar queda encima de la anterior hasta que la cierras.

```
private void btn_AgregarClientes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Agregar agmain = new Agregar();
    agmain.ShowDialog();
}
```

Puedes cerrar esa ventana con el botón de forma normal o con el código:

```
DialogResult = true; //o false
```

Eso cierra ventanas abiertas mediante ShowDialog() aunque los "Dialogs" generalmente son para cuadros de diálogo que retornan un valor, pero nadie impide que lo uses a tu modo.

Hay más formas pero con lo que hay deberías poder solucionar tu problema, aunque reitero que me parece muy extraño que tu ventana se duplique sin que tu sepas porqué si en el código mismo lo tienes hecho.

Answer (score 0):

hace tiempo tuve el mismo problema, te paso el siguiente código.

```
 private void Btn_ir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     MainWindow miwin=  Application.OpenForms.OfType<MainWindow>().SingleOrDefault();        
     this.Close();
 }
```